# Como faço para usar API google drive para envio e recebimento de áudio?

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

Queria saber como posso realizar envios e recebimento de arquivos de áudio via Google drive. Nunca usei a API do Google Drive, estou começando agora.

Pesquisei alguns exemplos na Internet, mas não consegui fazer.
Alguns Exemplos pesquisados e indicados:

https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094781/google-drive-unresolved-imports

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.google.api.client.http.FileContent

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164024/android-open-and-save-files-to-from-google-drive-sdk/12321331#12321331

Basicamente quero informar uma conta do Google Drive, enviar e receber gravações por la. Caso alguém possa me auxiliar ficaria muito grato. Toda dica é válida :)

Abraço e obrigado pela atenção.

Meu andamento:

Dependencias:
[image: Dependencias]
Permissões do Manifesto:
Ele informou no exemplo para importar uma permissão chamada USE_CREDENTIALS, mas ela não apareceu pra mim, logo, estou com apenas estas duas importadas. . .

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Código:
O código esta apresentando erro nos seguintes métodos:
response.getEntity(), gFile.getDownloadURL(), get.setHeader(), getGFileName(gFile), cliente.execute(), am.getAuthToken(am.getAccounts())[0], ..., nul);

Pelo que vi, o getGFileName(gFile) o tutorial manda eu fazer, mas não sei se os outros eu tenho que fazer na mão também, ou de repente eu importei ou fiz algo errado..

Código Abaixo

```
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback;
import android.accounts.AccountManagerFuture;
import android.accounts.AuthenticatorException;
import android.accounts.OperationCanceledException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveRequest;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
    am.getAuthToken(am.getAccounts()), "oauth2:" + DriveScopes.DRIVE, new Bundle(), true, new OnTokenAcquired(), null);//esta linha mostra o trecho "am.getAccounts())" sublinhado em vermelho mas quando clico, não apresenta nenhum erro. .

}


private class OnTokenAcquired implements AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> {

    boolean alreadyTriedAgain;
    File outFile; //sera o arquivo de envio


    @Override
    public void run(final AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> result) {
        try {
            final String token = result.getResult().getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
            HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
            JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
            Drive.Builder b = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null);
            b.setJsonHttpRequestInitializer(new JsonHttpRequestInitializer() {
                @Override
                public void initialize(JsonHttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                    DriveRequest driveRequest = (DriveRequest) request;
                    driveRequest.setPrettyPrint(true);
                    driveRequest.setKey("Minha chave de Api");//chave da API. . .
                    driveRequest.setOauthToken(token);
                }
            });

            final Drive drive = b.build();

            final com.google.api.services.drive.model.File body = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
            body.setTitle("My Test File");
            body.setDescription("A Test File");
            body.setMimeType("text/plain");

            // final FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/plain", "Arqiovp de envio");

            final FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/png", outFile);//outfile é o arquivo de envio. . .
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file = drive.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
                        alreadyTriedAgain = false; // Global boolean to make sure you don't repeatedly try too many times when the server is down or your code is faulty... they'll block requests until the next day if you make 10 bad requests, I found.
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        if (!alreadyTriedAgain) {
                            alreadyTriedAgain = true;
                            AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
                            am.invalidateAuthToken(am.getAccounts()[0].type, null); // Requires the permissions MANAGE_ACCOUNTS & USE_CREDENTIALS in the Manifest
                            am.getAuthToken(am.getAccounts())[0], "oauth2:" + DriveScopes.DRIVE, new Bundle(), true, new OnTokenAcquired(), null); //esta linha mostra o trecho "am.getAccounts())" sublinhado em vermelho mas quando clico, não apresenta nenhum erro. .
                        } else {
                            // Give up. Crash or log an error or whatever you want.
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).start();
            Intent launch = (Intent)result.getResult().get(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);
            if (launch != null) {
                startActivityForResult(launch, 3025);
                return; // Not sure why... I wrote it here for some reason. Might not actually be necessary.
            }
        } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
            // Handle it...
        } catch (AuthenticatorException e) {
            // Handle it...
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Handle it...
        }
    }



    private java.io.File downloadGFileToJFolder(Drive drive, String token, File gFile, java.io.File jFolder) throws IOException {
        if (gFile.getDownloadUrl() != null && gFile.getDownloadUrl().length() > 0 ) { //apresenta erro no getDownloadUrl(), não aparece esta opção no autoComplete enquanto digito, acho que devera ser implementado a mão . . .
            if (jFolder == null) {
                jFolder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                jFolder.mkdirs();
            }
            try {

                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();//era assim "HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();" mas como estava apresentando erros, deixei como está agora. .
                HttpGet get = new HttpGet(gFile.getDownloadUrl());
                get.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);

                InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                jFolder.mkdirs();
                java.io.File jFile = new java.io.File(jFolder.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + getGFileName(gFile)); // getGFileName() is my own method... it just grabs originalFilename if it exists or title if it doesn't.
                FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(jFile);
                byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length=inputStream.read(buffer))>0) {
                    fileStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                fileStream.close();
                inputStream.close();
                return jFile;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Handle IOExceptions here...
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            // Handle the case where the file on Google Drive has no length here.
            return null;
        }
    }
}


private java.io.File downloadGFileToJFolder(Drive drive, String token, File gFile, java.io.File jFolder) throws IOException {
    if (gFile.getDownloadUrl() != null && gFile.getDownloadUrl().length() > 0 ) {
        if (jFolder == null) {
            jFolder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            jFolder.mkdirs();
        }
        try {

            org.apache.http.client.HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(gFile.getDownloadUrl());
            get.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);

            InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
            jFolder.mkdirs();
            java.io.File jFile = new java.io.File(jFolder.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + getGFileName(gFile)); // getGFileName() is my own method... it just grabs originalFilename if it exists or title if it doesn't.
            FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(jFile);
            byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length=inputStream.read(buffer))>0) {
                fileStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            fileStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
            return jFile;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Handle IOExceptions here...
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        // Handle the case where the file on Google Drive has no length here.
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 3025) {
        switch (resultCode) {
            case RESULT_OK:
                AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(activity);
                am.getAuthToken(am.getAccounts())[0], "oauth2:" + DriveScopes.DRIVE, new Bundle(), true, new OnTokenAcquired(), null);
                break;
            case RESULT_CANCELED:
                // This probably means the user refused to log in. Explain to them why they need to log in.
                break;
            default:
                // This isn't expected... maybe just log whatever code was returned.
                break;
        }
    } else {
        // Your application has other intents that it fires off besides the one for Drive's log in if it ever reaches this spot. Handle it here however you'd like.
    }
}
```

Caso alguém possa me auxiliar, toda a dica é válida. Abraço!

Comment: Não de ligações, mas por ex. Armazenar um áudio gravado e enviar para o drive (tipo quando tu manda uma mensagem de áudio pelo watts).

Comment: Veja essa resposta no [SOEn](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12321331/5524514). Está bem detalhado, te dá um "norte".

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, vou dar uma olhada aqui, caso consiga ou não, aviso em breve :)

Comment: Muito bem explicado, mas não estou conseguindo pegar a sha1 do meu app, estou usando Android Studio, caso saiba como posso conseguir esta informação me avise por favor.

Comment: consegui gerar a sha1 pelo Prompt de Comando segundo ests instruções..  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELEsytc5LyU
vou seguir tentando aqui. Abraço!

Comment: Oi pessoal, bom, até então consegui gerar a SHA1. Importei todos os jar informado no link. Consegui também  cadastrar o app no Google Cloud Plataform em "Gerenciador de API >> Credenciais",  com isso gerei uma chave de API para usar no código java do app. Porém, após isso, não consegui seguir por aquele exemplo, editei o conteúdo da pergunta mostrando meu andamento até agora. O código ainda possui alguns erros, informei por comentários as linhas de erro.

Caso alguém possa me auxiliar a partir desta etapa, toda ajuda é válida, ficaria muito grato. Abraço!